# API calls to Heroku web-app running in webapp-runner eventually fail with NoSuchMethodError then NoClassDefFoundError in google.common

Tags: java, maven, heroku, guava, webapp-runner

I am running a war on Heroku using `webapp-runner`. I deploy the application using the `heroku-maven-plugin` version 1.2 via the following command: `mvn heroku:deploy-war`. Initially, the app works and all endpoints return valid responses. However, if I allow the app to idle long enough for Heroku to put it to sleep and then invoke an endpoint which calls into guava I receive a `NoSuchMethodError`:

```
2017-09-23T19:19:45.388865+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] in context with path [] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.ascii()Lcom/google/common/base/CharMatcher;] with root cause
2017-09-23T19:19:45.388866+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.ascii()Lcom/google/common/base/CharMatcher;
2017-09-23T19:19:45.388867+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$Alphabet.<init>(BaseEncoding.java:453)
2017-09-23T19:19:45.388868+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$Base64Encoding.<init>(BaseEncoding.java:892)
2017-09-23T19:19:45.388869+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.<clinit>(BaseEncoding.java:317)
...application specific stack trace
```

All subsequent calls to the same API produce a `NoClassDefFoundError` at the same point

```
2017-09-23T19:22:24.454901+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] in context with path [] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding] with root cause
2017-09-23T19:22:24.454903+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding 
...application specific stack trace
```

These issues seem to suggest that the guava jar is present at compile time but not present at runtime. However, I logged-in to the web dyno and verified that the guava jar was included in my `warfile`

```
my-mbp:TrickServer me$ heroku ps:exec
Establishing credentials... done
Connecting to web.1 on ⬢ myapp...
~ $ cd target/
~/target $ ls
MyApp.war  dependency  mvn-dependency-list.log  tomcat.52079
~/target $ jar -tf MyApp.war
...lots of dependencies...
WEB-INF/lib/google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar
WEB-INF/lib/guava-23.0.jar      <---guava
WEB-INF/lib/guava-jdk5-13.0.jar
...lots more dependencies...
```

I am struggling to explain why the endpoints work immediately after the app is deployed but later produce these errors. To me this behavior seems to suggest that Heroku is potentially supplying a different classpath when my app wakes up from sleep than when it is initially run or that Heroku is moving/cleaning up the guava jarfile.

Contents of my `Procfile`:

```
web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT --expand-war target/MyApp.war
```

Java Processes runnning on my web dyno:

```
~/target $ ps -ef | grep java
u30439       4     1  0 18:50 ?        00:00:44 java -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.timezone=UTC -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 52079 target/MyApp.war
u30439      27     4  0 18:50 ?        00:00:00 bash --login -c java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar $WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS --port 52079 target/MyApp.war
```

**Update 1**

Since I am invoking my webapp with the `--expand-war` argument I also checked the jarfiles in the expanded directory to verify that guava was present. It is:

```
~/target/tomcat.55320/webapps/expanded/WEB-INF/lib $ ls
...dependencies...
google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar
gson-2.2.4.jar
guava-23.0.jar
guava-jdk5-13.0.jar
...more dependencies...
```

**Update 2**

I added the following logic to the problematic web service to printout the classpath and the resources on it:

```
logger.info("System Classpath: " + System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
logger.info("Runtime Classes...");
    ClassLoader cl = UserService.class.getClassLoader();
    URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) cl).getURLs();
    for(URL url: urls){
        logger.info(url.getFile());
    }
```

The next time the error occurred I examined the logs and to my surprise found that the guava jar was present on the runtime classpath!

```
2017-09-24T12:07:40.843438+00:00 app[web.1]: [heroku-exec] ERROR: Could not connect to proxy:
2017-09-24T12:07:40.844145+00:00 app[web.1]: [heroku-exec] ERROR: Too many reconnect attempts. Waiting 30 seconds...
2017-09-24T12:07:52.671620+00:00 app[web.1]: Sep 24, 2017 12:07:52 PM org.myorg.server.web.services.MyService authenticate
2017-09-24T12:07:52.671631+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: System Classpath: target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar
2017-09-24T12:07:52.671931+00:00 app[web.1]: Sep 24, 2017 12:07:52 PM org.myorg.server.web.services.MyService authenticate
2017-09-24T12:07:52.671932+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Runtime Classes...
2017-09-24T12:07:52.672277+00:00 app[web.1]: Sep 24, 2017 12:07:52 PM org.myorg.server.web.services.MyService authenticate
2017-09-24T12:07:52.672279+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: /app/target/tomcat.28304/webapps/expanded/WEB-INF/classes/
....
2017-09-24T12:07:52.690304+00:00 app[web.1]: Sep 24, 2017 12:07:52 PM org.myorg.server.web.services.MyService authenticate
2017-09-24T12:07:52.690306+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: /app/target/tomcat.28304/webapps/expanded/WEB-INF/lib/google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar
2017-09-24T12:07:52.690501+00:00 app[web.1]: Sep 24, 2017 12:07:52 PM org.myorg.server.web.services.MyService authenticate
2017-09-24T12:07:52.690503+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: /app/target/tomcat.28304/webapps/expanded/WEB-INF/lib/guava-23.0.jar <--- Guava!!!
....
```

What is going on here? How do I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging, I discovered that my program had two different versions of Guava on the classpath (`guava-23.0.jar` & `guava-jdk5-13.0.jar`). The debugging tip suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474509/how-to-debug-nosuchmethoderror-exception) was necessary but not sufficient for me to get to the bottom of this.

When working with ClassLoaders it's important to remember that the `getClassLoader` method defined in the `.class` object returns a reference to the ClassLoader that originally loaded the class. To find the duplicate jar, it was crucial to invoke `classLoader.getResource("/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.class")` on the same ClassLoader which loaded the class that later failed with the `NoSuchMethodError`.

For posterity, the specific dependency which caused the conflict was `com.google.api-client`. I resolved it by adding the following `exclusion` to the dependency in my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two versions of guava or its related jars on your classpath. See [NoSuchMethodError exception when using com.google.common.base.Splitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257545/nosuchmethoderror-exception-when-using-com-google-common-base-splitter)